# How to upload Project+Dockerfile and build on AWS rather than build locally and upload the docker image to ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, node-modules

Since my project (nodejs) + Dockerfile is quite small (<10mb) but the docker image can be up 700mb.

As comparison, 
Building my docker locally (with pre-downloaded docker image base i.e. OS) and installing node_modules will take about 30 seconds.

While uploading the built docker image (700mb) to Amazon ECS takes me about 10 mins.

So I was thinking if I could just upload my project and Dockerfile to the AWS, running the build there, and I was expecting them to manage the intermediate/basic image as well.

I am expecting to spend my time to only uploading much smaller file 10mb compared to 700mb, and run the docker build for 30 seconds

Comment: I'm not aware that you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do that by two ways**

First one is the best approach and as follow by many industries standard and mention over here also.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-basics.html

**1st:**

Create small or micro t2 instance. Assign the `role to that instance` or You can `configure AWS cli`. Then In the EC2 Instance clone your project+dockerfile

So your build process and push will be faster as compared to from your local system.

```
eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)
docker build -t hello-world .
docker tag hello-world aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world
docker push aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world
```

**2st:**

In the container Instance clone your project+dockerfile and build your image in `ECS container instance` instead of local system and push that image to `AWS ECR`. as mention in step 1. You need to configure AWS cli or best approach is to assign the role to you container instance.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/